# Uploading blob files/images into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I had this php code that take values from an html form (name, file, photo, address,.....), and try to insert or update them in sql database.

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");

$id=$_REQUEST['id']; 

//Variable intilisation 
$name = '';
$remarcs = '';
$address = '';
$test_res = '';
$date = '';
$phone = '';
$new_path = '';



if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) {
    $remarcs = $_POST['remarcs'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) {
    $test_res = $_POST['test_res'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];
} 

if (isset ($_POST['date'])) {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
} 

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['phone_num'];
}

if(!empty($_FILES)){ //Check file is uploaded or not 
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file, $path);
        $new_path = $path;
        echo "Uploaded";
    } 
    if($check ==  false){
        echo "Not uploaded";
    }
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)){
$sql="  update patients set values
            name = '$name',
            echo_photo = 'NULL',
            echo_file = '$new_path',
            remarcs = '$remarcs',
            test_res = '$test_res',
            date = '$date',
            address = '$address',
            phone_num = '$phone' 
        WHERE id = ".$id;

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));
header("location:update_done.php");

}else{
        header("location:update_false.php");

}
if($result){
    echo $name."<p>\n</p>";
    echo $remarcs."<p>\n</p>";
    echo $test_res."<p>\n</p>";
    echo $address."<p>\n</p>";
    echo $phone."<p>\n</p>";  
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

The problem is that I am getting the following errors when only I upload a file shown in the image below:
[image]

And when I dont upload a file, I got an error: Please select a file.
Any help ? Thank you.

This is the html form:

```
<form action="update.php" id="Form2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="c">
<div align="center">
<?php echo "Updating information about Patient ".$row["name"]; ?>
<table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="3"  align="center">
  <th>Personal Informations</th>
<th>Test Results</th>

<tr><td>Name<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="name" placeholder="Patient Name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"/></td>
<td>Remarcs:<br>
  <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="remarcs" placeholder="Remarcs"><?php echo $row['remarcs'];?></textarea></td>
  <tr><td>Address<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>"/>
  </td>
<td>Test<br>  <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="test_res" placeholder="Test Result"><?php echo $row['test_res'];?></textarea></td></tr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number<br>
  <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $row['phone_num'];?>"/>
  </td>
<th>Files</th>
</tr>
  <td>Scanned Echo Photo<br>
  <input type="file" class="" name="echo_photo" id="echo_photo" placeholder="Add echo photo" value="<?php echo $row['echo_photo'];?>"/></td>
<td>Echo Files:<br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  value="<?php echo $row['echo_files'];?>"/><br></td>
  </tr></th></table>
  <div class="row" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnUploadId" class="large-btn" value="Update" onClick="btnOnClickUpload()">
      <input type="hidden" id="courseIdHidden" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" /></td></tr>
      </table></div>
</form>
```

Comment: check the values are posted properly to variables.

Comment: yes they are posted properly when i dont submit a file with them @Anish

Comment: Okay, sir now I got only 2 errors when I submit a file in the form: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\clinic form\update\update.php on line 41 AND ( ! ) Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\clinic form\update\update.php on line 43

Comment: can you paste the html form ?

Comment: Ok I will post it as answer to your question

Comment: No you can edit the same question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92919/discussion-between-anish-and-droidnation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialise the variable. I have added the entire code. You don't need to get $_POST['file'].

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="root"; // Mysql password
$db_name="clinic"; // Database name
$tbl_name="patients"; // Table name
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","clinic");

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];

 $name = '';
 $remarcs = '';
 $address = '';
 $test_res = '';
 $date = '';
 $phone = '';
  $new_path = '';

if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 }
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) {
 $remarcs = $_POST['remarcs'];
 }
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) {
$test_res = $_POST['test_res'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) {
  $address = $_POST['address'];
}

if (isset ($_POST['date'])) {
  $date = $_POST['date'];
}

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) {
 $phone = $_POST['phone_num'];
}

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ //Check file is uploaded or not

  $path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
  $new_path = $path;
  $sql=" update patients set 
  name = '$name',
  echo_photo = 'NULL',
  echo_file = '$new_path',
  remarcs = '$remarcs',
   test_res = '$test_res',
  date = '$date',
  address = '$address',
  phone_num = '$phone'
  WHERE id = ".$id;

  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '.   mysqli_error($con));

if($result){
 echo $name."<p>\n</p>";
 echo $remarcs."<p>\n</p>";
 echo $test_res."<p>\n</p>";
 echo $address."<p>\n</p>";
 echo $phone."<p>\n</p>";
 }
  echo "Uploaded";
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded";
 }
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Okay, sir now I got only 2 errors when I submit a file in the form: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\clinic form\update\update.php on line 41  AND ( ! ) Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\clinic form\update\update.php on line 43

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\clinic form\update\update.php on line 51

Comment: I have added the entire code after modifying. Please check it

Comment: use move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path); instead of copy

Comment: Please guys see my edited php code. Still dont work even though with no errors appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92925/discussion-between-arun-krish-and-droidnation).

Comment: Arun please add the code u send it in chat to make as an answer please

Comment: Dear arun, when I want to access one of the files uploaded into the folder and to the db, the file opens as "Unable to open files". And if it is an image, the image wont be shown. What is the problem

Comment: Can you post the code how you fetched file from folder and db?

Comment: I will post them here as an answer I hope that what you mean

Comment: you told an issue in image file opening..right?..I told that piece of code

Comment: Oh I fixed it. See your answer I already edit it now. It works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code:

```
if (isset ($_POST['name'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) { 
$remarcs = $_POST['remarcs']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) { 
$test_res = $_POST['test_res']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) { 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
} 

if (isset ($_POST['date'])) { 
$date = $_POST['date']; 
} 

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) { 
$phone = $_POST['phone_num']; 
} 

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ //Check file is uploaded or not 

$path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
//$path2 = "../uploads/".$_FILES['echo_photo']['name']; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){ 
$new_path = $path; 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET  
name = '$name', 
echo_files = '$new_path', 
remarcs = '$remarcs',
test_res = '$test_res', 
date = '$date', 
address = '$address', 
phone_num = '$phone' 
WHERE id = '$id'"; 

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));
```