# Encoding uploaded files name

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to ask, if I have a web form, and people use it to upload something to my db. If 2 persons uploaded the same file with the same name, in the uploads directory, one of them will replace the other. So I need to change the name of every file uploaded to db to : filename201405051200.pdf or jpg or...
Here we have the filename per example image1 and the numbers are the date and time of the uploads. So any help. I am using the code shown as an answer in the link below:

[Uploading blob files/images into Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251291/uploading-blob-files-images-into-mysql/33251351?noredirect=1#comment54319710_33251351)

I used this code:

```
$path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time())){
...
}
```

but now the format type of the file is replaced by the time. So if it is img.jpg it is now img85890338jpg and wont open properly

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please show us the code that you've already written.

Comment: see the link. First of all, the file is uploaded but when i want to downloaded by my site, it is downloaded but wont open properly. Anyway my problem is how to save a file by adding a name as I said in the question, see the link to see the code used.

Comment: you use rand(111111,999999) function with your file name for set unique file name.

Comment: sir I used this line of code, it works but it replaces the format type of the file so if the file is img1.jpg now it is img1_8573349jpg without a .jpg and cant open it: $path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
//$path2 = "../uploads/".$_FILES['echo_photo']['name']; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time())){ ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract the file extension:

```
$fileExt = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

After that you can create your new file name:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$fileExt)) {

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, but I prefer for now to use date and time: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.'_'.time().date().'.'.$ext) and $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);